# IBM BladeCenter S: How to configure new SAS disks

Tags: raid, sas, bladecenter

I have an IBM BladeCenter S, and I have added two new 450GB SAS disks.

I want to configure the disks as a RAID 0, and assign the new disks to one of the servers in the Bladecenter.

When I connect to the SAS Controller Module using the webclient, there are no options for setting up the RAID, only: "Health and monitoring" and "Configuration" (Zoning)

Please tell me how to configure my SAS disks. Is that possible using the web interface?
When I log into the Adv. Mgmt. Module, \MM Control \ License Mgr: 
Three options:

- IBM Bladecenter Open Fabric Manager
- IBM Bladecenter Adv. Open Fabric Manager
- IBM Bladecenter Open Fabric Manager plugin

Status for all these are "No license". Is it required to have a license for conf. the RAID. This is strange, since the Bladecenter have been running for five years.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken, you have to configure it from the BladeServer itself, not from its module.